# Vue computed array appends values instead of rewriting

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, computed-properties

I have an array called `contactDetails` that keeps a list of different contacts points (e.g. phone number, social media handle, etc) of the user. The available contact platforms are predefined in a list. I have a computed value that keeps track of which platforms the user has not added as a contact detail yet. The computed array is used in a select field for the user to choose from when creating a new contact detail.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            platforms: [
                {
                    text: 'WhatsApp',
                    value: 1,
                },
                {
                    text: 'Call',
                    value: 2,
                },
                {
                    text: 'Email',
                    value: 3,
                },
                {
                    text: 'LinkedIn',
                    value: 4,
                },
                {
                    text: 'TikTok',
                    value: 5,
                },
                {
                    text: 'Twitter',
                    value: 6,
                },
            ],
            contactDetails: [],
        },
        onAddContactDetails() {
            var selectedPlatform = this.platforms.find(obj => {
                return obj.value == this.platformId
            })

            var newContact = {
                platform: selectedPlatform.value,
                platformName: selectedPlatform.text,
                channel: this.channel,
                priority: this.contactPriorityId
            }
            this.contactDetails.push(newContact)
            this.updatePriority(newContact, this.contactDetails)

            this.platformId = null
            this.contactPriorityId = null
            this.channel = null

            this.platformList = null;
            this.isAddContact = false;
        },
        computed: {
            platformList() {
                var list = [];
                if (this.contactDetails.length == 0) {
                    return this.platforms;
                } else {
                    list = this.platforms;
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.contactDetails.length; i++) {
                        var id = this.contactDetails[i].platform;
                        for (var j = 0; j < this.platforms.length; j++) {
                            if (this.platforms[j].value == id) {
                                list.splice(j, 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return list;
            },
```

[image: Before adding a contact detail]

This is how the dropdown looks like before adding a new contact detail.

However, my computed property updates, but instead of refreshing the list, the new list is appended onto the existing options, thus causing duplication.

[image: After adding a new contact detail]

The original list + the new list of contact details, which is supposed to be (full list - contacts that the user has already added)

I would like to know how to fix this, and if there is a better way of setting the options available left for the user in the dropdown menu. Thanks!

Comment: For a start, you are mutating `this.platforms` in your computed property, which you should not do. Do `list = this.platforms.slice()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating `this.platforms` in the computed property; you should clone it first if you are going to mutate it:

```
list = this.platforms.slice()
```

I'm not sure what's causing the duplication though. You are only ever pushing to `contactDetails` and removing from `platforms`.

Your computed property can be simplified quite a bit:

```js
computed: {
  platformList() {
    // Filter platforms
    return this.platforms.filter(platform =>
      // Include this platform if there is no contact detail using that platform
      !this.contactDetails.some(contact =>
        contact.platform === platform.value
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping to simplify the computed property, I've decided to test out the code separately in a jsfiddle and it seems like the issue is with the custom select component I'm using in the project that isn't updating the options correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/wvco65th/